# How can one create a file shortcut inside the Android file system?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, file-system, home-screen-shortcuts

I don't want to create a file shortcut on the desktop, I want to create a shortcut inside the Pictures folder to the DCIM folder. My mom is able to handle tech stuff, she used to work for HP. But she's getting forgetful and keeps forgetting that I have told her multiple times that her photos are under DCIM and not Pictures. If I have to root her phone to make this work, that's not an issue, I have plenty of experience with that, and have already researched how to root her particular model of phone. I believe the version of Android on the phone (AT&T LG V20) is 7.0 Nougat. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: As a workaround, I suggested you introduce her to the gallery, there she can find all the pictures, and the file is called camera instead of dcim

Comment: The gallery works, but IMO it can be a rather convoluted mess and hard to find things in. On my phone for instance, I have tons of music on my micro SD card along with album cover jpegs. Gallery sees all those thumbs and absolutely pollutes my gallery with them. I have to scroll through hundreds of things just to find the download folder.

Comment: @Braden'sPC's There are many gallery apps that can exclude such images. You can even pin important folders like Camera. Downloads to the top so you don't have to scroll down everytime. If your favourite gallery app does not have this feature, just create an empty file named `.nomedia` and Android will exclude that folder by default in every gallery app.

Comment: Ooooh. Learning something new everyday. Thanks!

Comment: It's those little things in Android that you never hear about until you do lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called symbolic linking

`ln -s` command is your friend. Now depending on your device and the file manager you use, this process can differ. I don't think you'll need root for this, but if your device doesn't come with symbolic linking by default, you'll need root to add this.

And like the other comment said, it's better to use a Gallery app for photos rather than doing this.